# What was the literary origin of the idea that in the far future the moon would get closer to the Earth?

Tags: history-of, astronomy

Something that comes up a lot in science fiction novels that take place on Earth in the distant future is the idea that the moon will get closer to the Earth (sometimes close enough to share a common atmosphere).  This shows up in a wide range of works—for example, *[Earth's Last Citadel](https://archive.org/details/earthslastcitade00moor)* (1943) by C. L Moore and Henry Kuttner,* *[City at World's End](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_Science_Fiction_Novel_18_Edmond_Hamilton_City_at_Worlds_End_1953/mode/2up)* (1951) by Edmond Hamilton, and *[The Shadow of the Torturer](https://archive.org/details/shadowoftorturer0000wolf)* (1980) by Gene Wolfe.

However, this is not actually what physics predicts will happen, and I am wondering how this error made its way into science fiction.  I can understand (at a technical level) how this misconception may have arose.  It's fairly straightforward to realize that the Earth-moon system is gradually losing mechanical energy over time, largely as radiant heat.  A naive, first-semester classical mechanics calculation shows that a body moving in a fixed gravitational potential will indeed orbit more and more closely as it loses energy.  However, this overlooks the fact that the bulk of the internal energy locked up in the Earth-moon system is in the rotational kinetic energy of the Earth.  More careful calculations take advantage of the fact that while there is plenty of energy lost into space by electromagnetic radiation, very little total angular momentum is lost—although angular momentum can be transferred between the Earth and the moon via tidal torques.  So the slowing down of the system will, to a good approximation, preserve angular momentum.  Since the angular momentum is predominantly in the orbital revolution of the moon, the net process will be a slowing of the Earth's diurnal rotation, with the moon receding farther away to keep the angular momentum the same.

This was all known to astronomers by the early twentieth century at the latest.  (Calculating the rate at which the moon will recede is a much harder problem that depends on the internal structure of the Earth and which people are still working on.)  However, the simplistic idea of the moon getting closer seemed to be widespread in science fiction well beyond that time.  At some point, this idea must have been introduced into the genre, and I am wondering if it can be identified what works were responsible.  Or, if not, in what time periods did this erroneous notion appear and grow prominent.

*[A number of the covers](https://www.blackgate.com/2015/05/01/vintage-treasures-earths-last-citadel-by-c-l-moore-and-henry-kuttner/) for *Earth's Last Citadel* have featured the nearby moon (which, by virtue of its nearness, causes massive fast-moving tidal bores) quite prominently.  This one is perhaps the most evocative.

[image: Earth's Last Citadel]

Comment: I'm half-way through the post. Interesting question. If I forget a huge bulk of what I've learned at school, and make a basic assumption (which I think you already did in the question), I could say that anything would lose velocity over time, which means the moon would be inevitably pulled into the Earth as time passes by. Of course, this is just speculation.

Comment: I'm no scientist, but I'm pretty sure that the latest thinking in astrophysics circles is that the moon is made of cheese.

Comment: @Valorum Those aren't astrophysics "circles."  They are astrophysics "wheels."

Comment: "This was all known to astronomers by the early twentieth century at the latest.": Other influences aside, Earth would become tidally locked to the moon, and then the system would slowly decay due to interactions with the sun and other planets until the moon came too close and broke up. We now know that the sun will enter its red giant phase before Earth is even locked, making this scenario impossible, but I'm not sure this was understood as early as you say.

Comment: @Clockwork The moon is indeed losing orbital velocity, which means that it is moving *away* from the earth.

Comment: I thought I had an answer to this question in The Time Machine by H. G. Wells, when the Time Traveler travels into the far future. The Earth becomes tidally locked with the dim sun, but whether he sees the moon at all is ambiguous.

Comment: Not an answer because I can’t verify it right now: I think one of the earlier stories in Asimov’s anthology “Before the Golden Age” might have mentioned that concept. Maybe “The Jameson Satellite” by Neil R. Jones?

Comment: A relevant question from another stack about the actual physics:  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/54424

Answer (score 12):

**1930:** [*Last and First Men*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?541), a novel by [Olaf Stapledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olaf_Stapledon), available at [Project Gutenberg Australia](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0601101h.html).

From Chapter XII, Part 3:

> The Fifth Men had long ago fashioned for themselves an all-embracing and minutely coherent system of natural sciences, every factor in which had been put to the test a thousand times and had never been shaken. Imagine, then, their bewilderment at this extraordinary discovery. In ages when science was still fragmentary, a subversive discovery entailed merely a reorganization of some one department of science; but by now, such was the coherence of knowledge, that any minute discrepancy of fact and theory must throw man into a state of complete intellectual vertigo.
>
> **The evolution of the lunar orbit had, of course, been studied from time immemorial. Even the First Men had learned that the moon must first withdraw from and subsequently once more approach the earth, till it should reach a critical proximity and begin to break up into a swarm of fragments likes the rings of Saturn. This view had been very thoroughly confirmed by the Fifth Men themselves. The satellite should have continued to withdraw for yet many hundreds of millions of years; but in fact it was now observed that not only had the withdrawal ceased, but a comparatively rapid approach had begun.**
>
> Observations and calculations were repeated, and ingenious theoretical explanations were suggested; but the truth remained completely hidden. It was left to a future and more brilliant species to discover the connexion between a planet's gravitation and its cultural development. Meanwhile, the Fifth Men knew only that the distance between the earth and the moon was becoming smaller with ever-increasing rapidity.
>
> This discovery was a tonic to a melancholy race. Men turned from the tragic past to the bewildering present and the uncertain future.
>
> For it was evident that, if the present acceleration of approach were to be maintained, the moon would enter the critical zone and disintegrate in less than ten million years; and, further, that the fragments would not maintain themselves as a ring, but would soon crash upon the earth. Heat generated by their impact would make the surface of the earth impossible as the home of life. A short-lived and short-sighted species might well have considered ten million years as equivalent to eternity. Not so the Fifth Men. Thinking primarily in terms of the race, they recognized at once that their whole social policy must now be dominated by this future catastrophe. Some there were indeed who at first refused to take the matter seriously, saying that there was no reason to believe that the moon's odd behaviour would continue indefinitely. But as the years advanced, this view became increasingly improbable. Some of those who had spent much of their lives in exploration of the past now sought to explore the future also, hoping to prove that human civilization would always be discoverable on the earth in no matter how remote a future. But the attempt to unveil the future by direct inspection failed completely. It was surmised, erroneously, that future events, unlike past events, must be strictly non-existent until their creation by the advancing present.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments above, I think that the ultimate source of this idea is scientific.  Because of the gravitational interaction of the Earth's tidal bulge with the Moon, angular momentum is being transferred from Earth's rotation to the Moon's orbit, and if nothing intervenes, this process should continue until the Earth and Moon are tidally locked together, with the Earth rotating in synchrony with the Moon's orbit around the Earth.  This is not the end of the story, though, since the Earth's rotation continues to slow owing to the tidal effect of the Sun, so that the process reverses itself.  To quote from  Jeffreys 1929:

> The matter will not be closed when this state is reached, however. The
> solar tides will continue to operate on the earth and lengthen its period
> of rotation. Thus the period of rotation of the earth will come to be
> longer than the period of revolution of the moon. A reference to 14·1
> will show that when this happens the further course of the evolution is
> considerably altered. A fixed point *P* on the earth’s surface will move
> round more slowly than the point where the moon is in the zenith... [Therefore, the effect of the tides] on the moon will be to retard its revolution
> and make it return to the earth, and the earth’s rotation will at the same
> time be accelerated. Thus the moon will gradually return towards the
> earth, the earth’s rotation meanwhile being retarded by the solar tides and
> accelerated by the lunar ones. This process will continue till the moon is at
> last dragged down to within a distance of the earth so short that it will be
> broken up by the action of the tides raised in it by the earth*; it will then
> ultimately form a system like Saturn’s ring, but much more massive.
> * Cf. Darwin, *The Tides*, 1911, 338-345. The critical distance of about twice the radius
> of the earth is known as Roche’s limit.

Jeffreys gives a time of around 50 billion years before the Earth and the Moon become tidally locked but doesn't give an estimate of the length of time it will take the Moon to return to the Earth.  Using a simplified model, Sasaki et al. 2012 give a time of around 6 billion years before the Earth and the Moon become tidally locked and around 68 billion years before the Moon finally approaches the Earth.  Of course, the Sun is forecast to evolve into a red giant and later into a white dwarf in a few billion years, which might interfere with these tidal processes.

References:

Jeffreys 1929: §14·52, *The Earth*, Harold Jeffreys, 2nd ed., Cambridge, 1929.

Sasaki et al. 2012: "Outcomes and Duration of Tidal Evolution in a Star-Planet-Moon System",  Takashi Sasaki, Jason W. Barnes, and David P. O'Brien, *The Astrophysical Journal*, **754** (2012), #1, 51, https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/754/1/51.

Comment: That makes sense.  Awareness that the Earth-moon system would be disrupted by the sun's red giant phase came much later, so there may have been no awareness that the system would never get beyond the lunar recession stage.